# How to avoid JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE and gracefully terminate the swing program

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I don't like the `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` option very much. If there's a thread writing a file, or downloading something the option will be killed before it can complete. Instead, I was trying to terminate the program gracefully by destroying the GUI window:

```
   /**
    * Terminates the whole program while saving settings.
    */
   public void Terminate() {
     //gui is JFrame representing the application window
     gui.setVisible(false);
     gui.dispose();
     gui.destroyTray();
     //Stop tool thread if running
     if(ToolRunning())
       StopTool();
     //Save settings
     if(settings==null) {
       System.out.println("Settings is null!");
       return;
     }
     try {
       settings.loadSettingsFromBoundFields();
       settings.saveToFile(SETTINGS_FILE, false);
     }
     catch(IOException e) {
       System.err.println("Problem saving settings:");
       e.printStackTrace(System.err);
     }
     //Here, no non-deamon threads should be running (daemon thread does not prolong the applicatione execution).
   }
```

But the program keeps running and the Swing threads do not exit when I `dispose()` the `JFrame`. What else could be blocking Swing? When I made a simpler program using the same approach (hide window and `dispose()`) it worked. This means complexity of my project is hiding something that leaked. How can I find what is blocking Swing threads from terminating?

Comment: setVisible(false) == dispose() if JVM is still alive

Comment: to try WindowListener/State/e.i.

Comment: 1. (There is no ...meta many times.) we aren't help desk, 2. (to avoids wrong answers here) there are two kind of processes that you would need to finalize/close() deamon and non_deamon threads, 3. How can I find what is blocking Swing threads from terminating? - JProfiler shows you all mess that isn't finalize/close() at runtime, incl. class/void/ variable name/inheritance or their nested API object

Comment: @mKorbel I don't understand your `1.`, try more words and more grammar. The rest of your comment shows poor understanding of the problem - I am not looking for the threads - I know that these are AWT threads. I want to find out what keeps them running.

Comment: `I am not looking for the threads` - use JProfiler, there you can to see your thread, `if you really want to find out what keeps them running`, one of three reason why I closed this one as too broad, because nobody knows where is the issue (I'm bet that problem is hiberantions or swapping in Laptop)

Comment: @mKorbel How can I better express **not**? Please try [this handy tool for better understanding of my comment and your reply](https://translate.google.com/#sk/en/Ja%20neh%C4%BEad%C3%A1m%20vl%C3%A1kna%20-%20pou%C5%BEite%20JProfiler%2C%20tam%20m%C3%B4%C5%BEete%20vidie%C5%A5%20va%C5%A1e%20vl%C3%A1kno). Also please, no matter what your good intentions are, please do not comment on my posts. You allways produce endless debate full of misunderstanding because you do not read other's posts carefully. I wonder how did you manage to avoid learning English after earning so much reputation on this site.

Comment: then is better to try assembler or cobol (processor price v.s. salary), to the rest - this is called justice, as aside I can post comment or answer, where is/can/it should be important, when I want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html , i.e.  Frame.getFrames